Show message when map returns no value
i have 2 arrays categorias and noticias;
categorias is like this:
export const Categorias = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "actualidade",
    slug: "actualidade",
  },
...
]

and noticias is something like this:
export const Noticias = [
  {
    id: 1,
    titulo: "titulo da primeira notícia",
    slug: "titulo-da-primeira-notícia",
    texto:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc.",
    img: "https://picsum.photos/id/0/5000/3333",
    cat: "politica",
    destaque: true,
  },
...
]

on the homepage i have this code that shows 4 news per category:
{cats.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <section className={`noticias ${item.name}`} key={index}>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="title">
                <h3>
                  {item.name}
                  <Link to={`/noticias/${item.slug}`}>
                    <p>ver todas</p>
                  </Link>
                </h3>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="blocks">
              {[...news]
                .reverse()
                .filter(
                  (noticia) =>
                    noticia.cat === item.slug && noticia.destaque !== true
                )
                .slice(0, 4)
                .map((noticia, idx) => {
                  return <BlockNoticia key={idx} item={noticia} id={idx} />;
                })}
            </div>
          </section>
        );
      })}

I have left some categories with no news on purpose so i can show a message when there are none.
This is working fine except when there are no news from a category.
How can i show a message like "there are no news in this category"?

https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering

Get the number of news after .filter. If it's 0, print the message, otherwise print the news.

Please note the line with the comment. That will only show if news length is zero (or nullish which shouldn't generally be the case).
{cats.map((item, index) => {
        let filteredNews = [...news]
          .reverse()
          .filter((noticia) => noticia.cat === item.slug && noticia.destaque !== true)
          .slice(0, 4);
        return (
          <section className={`noticias ${item.name}`} key={index}>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="title">
                <h3>
                  {item.name}
                  <Link to={`/noticias/${item.slug}`}>
                    <p>ver todas</p>
                  </Link>
                </h3>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="blocks">
              {filteredNews.length ? (
                filteredNews.map((noticia, idx) => {
                  return <BlockNoticia key={idx} item={noticia} id={idx} />;
                })
              ) : (
                <p>No news in this category</p> /**Put any message you wan't here */
              )}
            </div>
          </section>
        );
      })}

